# How can I use fs node module inside an AngularJS application with Electron?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron

How can I use fs node module inside an AngularJS application ?

I would like to include fs module from node.js in my application AngularJS

I create an application with Electron with an export file. At the moment I have a basic export,

```
$scope.exportProject = function () {
    var blob  = new Blob(['the_content'], {type: 'text/json'}),
        event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        file  = document.createElement('a');

    // Name file
    file.download = 'my_config';

    // Create link
    file.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    file.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/json', file.download, file.href].join(':');

    // Init event
    event.initEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

    // Dispatch event
    file.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

but when I click on my button export, there is a temporary file and I don't want it.

If I use FS from node, I think it will be ok, no temporary file.

Comment: This looks like XY problem. Why to not use `fs` from main process?

Comment: Do you have an example please ?

Comment: Not really, sorry. Send data from renderer to main and write it with `fs` in main. That's where the border between renderer and main processes lies. I would suggest to make some reading about Electron IPC if you haven't a chance before, e.g. http://blog.doselect.com/post/138215955198/renderer-main-process-communication-in-electron

Comment: Thx for this paper ! Use fs in main it's easy, but use fs in function from angular...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, No.

If you are using AngularJS and creating an Electron application (Desktop application built with Web Technologies) -- then the answer becomes, Maybe.

Comment: I updated my post ! Yes, I use electron, do you have an idea ?